# Missing collection name in success message when adding question to an existing collection

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

In Stack Overflow for Teams (Business), the new feature "Collections" has a bug.

When a question that is not currently included in any collection, is added to an existing collection using the Collections sidebar module,

> [image]

the success message is missing the Collection name.

> [image]

Win 10 Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit), userscripts toggled off.